# Android UI Issue

Tags: android, user-interface, android-xml

Guys I'm new to Android actually, i created an android UI with eclipse, its look like this(image), it is not a real android UI, how can i get android real element styles? Guys please help out me. I'm using android 4.01 project.
My main.xml is as follows

Please look at this screenshot:

[image: image 1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please upload the image here? I am unable to access the link as I am on job now!

Comment: I'm not allowed to upload images here dude! :( can't you see the image from here ?

Comment: Its hard to understand what you mean by "it is not a real android UI, how can i get android real element styles? ". And the xml you have given here,isn't that working?

Comment: what do you mean with `it is not a real android UI`? This is the new Holo Theme that comes with Android 4 Ice Cream Sandwich. This is the purest Android UI you can get... (btw: `style="@drawable/ic_launcher"` is wrong! You need to set a style, not a drawable!)

Comment: Thanks is it ? how can i get theme which use gingerbread ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your android project to 3.0 or 2.3, maybe this will help you